# Google SSO with JWT authentication with Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, jwt, google-sso

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), they're no longer using the previous SSO mechanism as of this month.

However, I'm not able to get Laravel Socialite working with the new mechanism, [which uses a JWT token instead](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#html).

I keep getting - perhaps predictably:

```
`400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }
```

as there's no longer a code being sent through.

I'm using Laravel 8 though I don't see any major changes. I'm happy to paste my code though it's all very standard, just adding stateless() to the Socialite calls.

I'm wondering if it's just known that Socialite doesn't handle the JWT method, and I should just go about building the mechanism myself via the Google API.

Comment: [It is not yet supported but there are plans on adding support](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/634). You might need to implement it yourself. Keep a close eye on the repo for any developments on this issue or pull requests to help you along the way